# Lidar data for Israel

Tags: data, lidar, israel

Are there any public sources for LIDAR data for the country of Israel? Searching online has not lead me to find any sources out there.

Comment: this may well be better asked on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing this answer, the only one I know of are the coastal cliffs between Herzliya and Hadera on OpenTopography

http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/datasetMetadata?otCollectionID=OT.102016.2039.1

Answer (score 0):

http://donnees4free.blogspot.com/2016/10/new-free-lidar-data-sources-list.html

Scroll down the very end there for you to check it out..

You might also want to contact the universities in Israel and check their geography department they might have. ? They may be telling you where to find...